# UPPER case in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, string, format

I build a lightning component for my org. One of my attribute is a String value inside a collection of a custom object. Somentimes this String is in lowercase and sometimes is in uppercase. I want to show it in Uppercase always. How can I do that.

My code sample:

```
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.records}" var="record" indexVar="idx">
                            <tr>
                                <td data-label="{!field}" title="{!field}">
                                    <div><a data-record="{!record.Id}" onclick="{!c.goToDetailView}">
                                        {!record.FirstName}
                                        </a></div>
                                </td>

[...]
</aura:iteration>
```

Answer (score 7):

You make the text as uppercase by using `text-transform:uppercase` css. More info on text-transform can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform)

```
<div>
<a style="text-transform:uppercase" data-record="{!record.Id}" onclick="{!c.goToDetailView}">
     {!record.FirstName}
</a>
</div>
```

You can use `class="slds-text-title--caps"` if you are using SLDS thanks @sfdcfox.

Comment: `class="slds-text-title--caps"` will work in Lightning, too.

Comment: thank you I use class="slds-text-title--caps" and solved my problem

Comment: @L.benedettini please mark as best answer, thanks!